# angular component resolved values showing undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I'm using Angular JS (version 1.5.9) and the Angular UI Router (version 1.0.0-rc.1).
When I'm trying to access binding values in component controller, it is showing `undefined`. Below I shared my code.

What wrong with my code? Could you please guide me how to resolve this issue?

**router.config**

```
     $stateProvider.state('app.user-datshboard', {
        url: '/dashboard/:user',
        views: {
            'header@':{
                templateUrl : getView('user-navbar')
            },
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: getView('user-dashboard')
            },
            'footer':{}
        },
        params: {
            user : null
        },
        resolve: {
            OurUser : function(){
                return 'nihao';
            }
        }

        }
    })
```

**component**

```
 class UserDashboardController{
   constructor(API,$log,$state,$stateParams,$scope){
    'ngInject';
    //
    $log.log(this);
    this.API = API;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$log = $log;
    this.$timeout = $timeout;
    this.$state = $state;
    this.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    this.$log.log(this.OurUser);
  }
 }

 export const UserDashboardComponent = {
templateUrl: './views/app/components/user-dashboard/user-    dashboard.component.html',
controller: UserDashboardController,
controllerAs: 'vm',
bindings: { OurUser : '=' }
 }
```

**Error Screen**

```
 [error screen][1]
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to use $onInit in your Component Controller check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43078999/3842364

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your `OurUser` in any controller or service, for example:

```
constructor(API, $log, $state, $stateParams, $scope, OurUser){
  // here you have access to OurUser
}
```

this way you do not need `bindings: { OurUser : '=' }`

Comment: getting error this "Unknown provider: OurUserProvider <- OurUser"

Comment: make sure that your component controller is used under the route path /dashboard/<user>. `OurUser` should be injectable for any service or controller under this route. See also this article: https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/#coupling-routing-logic-with-controllers

Comment: i tried many times but no use. please provide any bit of code for this...

Comment: i'm using jadjoubran/laravel5-angular-material-starter.

Comment: need to see your implementation, please upload your code to plunker or codepen and I will try to help. See official examples: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve. I also forked for you a plunker demo (http://plnkr.co/edit/5rpPZET2GOrMxapa2N8h?p=preview) an added your resolve there in `script.js` file (when previewing, press *Go to state 2* button)