# Component : ui-router resolve will not inject into controller, data undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have this problem using resolve with component & ui-router, the data "after" resolving promise are "undefined" in a controller

**Service:**

```
class userService {
  constructor ($http, ConfigService, authService) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.API_URL = `${ConfigService.apiBase}`;
    this.authService = authService;
  }


testAuth () {
    return this.$http.get(this.API_URL + '/test-auth')
 }

getCollaboratores () {
    return this.$http.get(this.API_URL + '/collaboratores').then( 
          (resolve) => {   // promise resolve
          console.log('Success',resolve.data);
     }
   )
 }

getAccount () {
   var config = {
   headers: { "X-Shark-CollaboratoreId" : "1"}
  };
  return this.$http.get(this.API_URL + '/accounts' + '/' + 1,     config).then( 
          (resolve) => {   // promise resolve
              console.log('Success',resolve.data);
      }
   )
 }
```

**Module/Component/Routing:**

```
.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
 "ngInject";

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

 $stateProvider
   .state('core', {
      redirectTo: 'dashboard',
      url: '/core',
      component: 'core',
      resolve: {
        userdata: (userService) => {
            return userService.getCollaboratores();
        },
        accdata: (userService) => {
            return userService.getAccount();
        }
      }

    });
})
```

**Controller:**

```
let self;

class CoreController {
  constructor($state,userService,authService,userdata,accdata) {
    this.name = 'core';
    this.$state = $state;
    this.userService = userService;
    this.authService = authService;
    this.userdata = userdata;
    this.accdata = accdata;
    console.log('name',this.name);
    self = this;
    console.log('userdata',self);
  }
}

CoreController.$inject = ['$state','userService',     'authService','userdata','accdata'];

export default CoreController;
```

After injecting in the controller the object "resolved" by promise after "http" call

```
 this.userdata = userdata;
 this.accdata = accdata;
```

are undefined!!!

where is the bug.??

thanks a lot...

Comment: what is the output for `console.log('Success',resolve.data);
`?

Comment: the ouput is correct:     Success Object {data: Array[1]}.... without RESOLVE all code work correctly, I try to use resolve for render the view after promise resolve.

Answer (score 6):

Change the getCollaboratores function to below :

```
getCollaboratores () {
  return this.$http.get(this.API_URL + '/collaboratores').then( 
      (resolve) => {   // promise resolve
      console.log('Success',resolve.data);
      return resolve;
   });
}
```

Do the same with other one getAccount (i.e inside the success callback return resolve).

This will solve your problem.

Reason is once you chain success callbacks, 1st callback as to return the something which can be the arguments for the 2nd callback. Since the success callback in service was not returning anything(default return value of a function in js is undefined), hence resolved value was not available in the controller.

Comment: Callback not `not returning anything`. `return undefined` added to js function if nothing overrides `return` directive.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Using_the_then_method for details about `.then()`. What is actually `resolve`?. From sources `557: @return {object} Promise for an object that contains the resolved return value of all invocables, as well as any inherited and local values`. This means your resolve actually a `Promise(() => return Promise.all(resolve.keys))`. And most from them return `undefined`.

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand your feedback, can you indent correctly the answer. thanks.

Comment: I would also prefer this.

Comment: @SimoneLazzaroni Can you please set up a fiddle or plunkr for your code to test. The above solution worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

What version of angularjs are you using?

Remember that in 1.6, a `then` callback now receives 4 parameters: `data`, `status`, `headers`, `config` and `statusText`.

In this scenario, a `resolve.data` could result in an `undefined` value.

More info on docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Hi @AlexSuch  i use Angular 1.5.9

Answer (score 0):

I see that you relate to a component in your state not to a controller, so you should create a component and bind the resolved values to it.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .component('core', {
        templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
        controller: CoreController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindings: {
          userdata: '<',
          accdata: '<'
        }
    });
```

And to get the resolve data in your component controller do this:

```
const vm = this;
vm.$onInit = () => {
    console.log('userdata: ', vm.userdata);
    console.log('accdata: ', vm.accdata);
}
```